#CrewAI:Agent unable to Access search model
I've built a search internet tool with EXA and although the API key seems to work , my agent indicates that he can't use it.
Any help would be appreciated as I am beginner when it comes to coding.
Here are the codes that I've used for the search tools and the agents using crewAI.
Thank you in advance for your help :
import os
from exa_py import Exa
from langchain.agents import tool
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
class ExasearchToolSet():
def _exa(self):
return Exa(api_key=os.environ.get('EXA_API_KEY'))
@tool
def search(self,query:str):
"""Useful to search the internet about a a given topic and return relevant results"""
return self._exa().search(f"{query}",
use_autoprompt=True,num_results=3)
@tool
def find_similar(self,url: str):
"""Search for websites similar to url.
the url passed in should be a URL returned from 'search'"""
return self._exa().find_similar(url,num_results=3)
@tool
def get_contents(self,ids: str):
"""gets content from website.
the ids should be passed as a list,a list of ids returned from 'search'"""
ids=eval(ids)
contents=str(self._exa().get_contents(ids))
contents=contents.split("URL:")
contents=[content[:1000] for content in contents]
return "\n\n".join(contents)
class TravelAgents:
def __init__(self):
    self.OpenAIGPT35 = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7)
    
    

def expert_travel_agent(self):
    return Agent(
        role="Expert travel agent",
        backstory=dedent(f"""I am an Expert in travel planning and logistics, 
                        I have decades experiences making travel itineraries,
                        I easily identify good deals,
                        My purpose is to help the user to profit from a marvelous trip at a low cost"""),
        goal=dedent(f"""Create a 7-days travel itinerary with detailed per-day plans,
                        Include budget , packing suggestions and safety tips"""),
        tools=[ExasearchToolSet.search,ExasearchToolSet.get_contents,ExasearchToolSet.find_similar,perform_calculation],
        allow_delegation=True,
        verbose=True,llm=self.OpenAIGPT35,
        )
    

def city_selection_expert(self):
    return Agent(
        role="City selection expert",
        backstory=dedent(f"""I am a city selection expert,
                        I have traveled across the world and gained decades of experience.
                        I am able to suggest the ideal destination based on the user's interests, 
                        weather preferences and budget"""),
        goal=dedent(f"""Select the best cities based on weather, price and user's interests"""),
        tools=[ExasearchToolSet.search,ExasearchToolSet.get_contents,ExasearchToolSet.find_similar,perform_calculation]
               ,
        allow_delegation=True,
        verbose=True,
        llm=self.OpenAIGPT35,
    )
def local_tour_guide(self):
    return Agent(
        role="Local tour guide",
        backstory=dedent(f""" I am the best when it comes to provide the best insights about a city and 
                        suggest to the user the best activities based on their personal interest 
                         """),
        goal=dedent(f"""Give the best insights about the selected city
                    """),
        tools=[ExasearchToolSet.search,ExasearchToolSet.get_contents,ExasearchToolSet.find_similar,perform_calculation]
               ,
        allow_delegation=False,
        verbose=True,
        llm=self.OpenAIGPT35,
    )

I have tested the API keys, Tried playing with prompt. I don't understand why the agent can't have Access to the search tool
